# Dynamic Tables of a Common Type - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, dbcontext

I have an Entity called "MyEntity".

Now, In my database, every month a new table is created called "MyEntityJan2017", the following month will be "MyEntityFeb2017" etc...

Normally I return my entities like this:

```
public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntity{ get; set; }
```

But I can't do this here as there is no such class as "MyEntityJan2017"

The repository methods for these tables use the returned DbSet and query them using Linq.

How do I return a DbSet for dynamically created tables?

The only solution I have so far is to query these tables the old fashioned way as below but I'd rather not.

```
var resultSet = dataContext.Database.SqlQuery<MyEntity>(sqlQuery, paramList);
```

Comment: I would go for stored proc :) little off the track but then you can manage this all out of EF becuase I am not sure this can be achieved in EF.

Comment: @YashveerSingh The problem is that I'd then have to move all the functionality into StoredProceedures. All the queries already exist in LINQ.  Is there a way to return a table/dbset from a stored procedure as such that can be queried?  ie DbSet<StoredProceedure> MyTable ?

Comment: one option is to you can do is to return all data from stored proc and then you can materliaze it to MyEntity and then use linq on top of it . this way  you can create dynamic queries in proc and then converte all data to single entity using DBReader and Materializers and work with linq .Not sure if this is the best approach

Comment: @YashveerSingh Unfortunately, the tables are stats related.  They are at least 10mil rows each and growing.  Pulling all that data in without first filtering causes memory issues.

Comment: oh I understand . but we can do something like which is fast and consume less memory . So if we filter most of data on stored proc then you will no issues of memory .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer to this is that you can't with EF.  As [Yashveer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4861332/yashveer-singh) suggested, it is best to simply use a stored proc to return the data that is needed,

Comment: Must. Not. Change. [The realest answer on SO](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/7852ws/this_is_not_the_answer_i_was_looking_for/)